# MySQL - SELECT with division of two values returns different number of rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one simple table 'drugs' with 4 columns: 'EAN', 'ATC', 'amount', 'price'. EANs and ATCs are some kind of drugs codes, while amount is basically the number of drug packages that have been bought for the given price. Non of them is unique, rows can (and probably do) duplicate. I need cost of a single package, so I used:

```
SELECT EAN, ATC, ROUND((price/amount),2) FROM drugs
```

but result has fewer rows. To be precise, drugs has 23,658,687 total rows, while query result has only 23,657,443. What happened to that 1,244 records? I thought that result will have exactly the same rows, but with new computed values in each row instead of old two.

Comment: All the records in `drugs` should be appearing.  Is there any chance the table was modified since you obtained the `23,658,687` total?

Comment: If you don't have any `where` criteria, then this query would return the same number of rows as `select * from drugs`... Can you post a sql fiddle with your problem?

Comment: May be some rows have `amount = 0`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it's local mysql service, I'm the only one working on it, it's been 23,658,687 total since creation of that table few weeks ago.

Comment: @sgeddes That's what I thought, but... I'm gonna make sql fiddle, but tomorrow, please stay tuned, ok?

Comment: @DoNhuVy yes, some have, but then I got NULL which shows up in result in proper rows.

Comment: Try adding where 1=1 and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Ok @Missy, WHERE 1=1 worked. Please put this as an answer with some explanation why it behaves that way.

Comment: Glad it worked.  Please uptick if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
   SELECT EAN, ATC, ROUND((price/amount),2) FROM drugs where 1=1
```

and that will select all your records.  I have no idea why it works but it does.  I'm guessing that there were some exact duplicate records that weren't getting returned and the new WHERE statement forces them to appear.